# Updating Worksheet if different information on another Worksheet - Formula or VBA?

Tags: excel

I have worksheet 2 that has possible updated information for worksheet 1. I want to compare worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 and if there are any differences update worksheet 1 with the information in worksheet 2 and change Column A in that row to "Update".

Example: I have an ID number in B2 in worksheet 1. I want to see if it matches an ID number in worksheet 2 anywhere in column B. If it does I want it to check the address in worksheet 1 S2 and compare it to the same id address in worksheet 2 which is in column S. If they are different update worksheet 1 (S2) with the address in worksheet 2 and change worksheet A2 to "Update".

This is the first step but if someone can help me with this I might figure out the rest.

I will need to check other columns. If someone could show me how to combine multiple checks into the same formula that would be great. For example check the address and County name (worksheet 1 x2, worksheet 2 x:x) and check the age (worksheet 1 af2, worksheet 2 af:af).

Comment: I'm no expert in excel, but it seems to be too big a task for formula. A chunk of VB code should work better, I think.

Comment: I think this would work with a [multi variable index/match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) formula. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What @SergioTulentsev said. This could be done more easily with VBA. However if you insist on a formula, a set of check columns with a new formulas for each column you would like to verify with a VLOOKUP or an INDEX/MATCH could work. Something along the lines of =vlookup(b2,Worksheet2!b2:d50,2,0)=C2 (assuming that column C holds the address data you want to verify in each sheet). Then just take each of your check columns and put it in a =if(OR(f2:h2),"UPDATE","") type formula.

Comment: Thanks Scott your answer for Vlookup just clikced with me and it is getting the job done.